# What's a good location for permanently storing Jenkins artifacts?

Tags: jenkins, repository, artifact

I was recently put in charge of all Jenkins-related work at my job, and was tasked with storing build artifacts from our declarative pipelines in a place where:
- They are accessible to everyone on the team
- They can be stored for long periods of time

Ideally they would be visible on the Jenkins interface, where they appear when using the default 'archiveArtifacts' command. I know this saves them in the JENKINS_HOME directory. The problem is that I have to discard old builds to avoid running out of space and the artifacts are deleted with them. Furthermore, I don't have access to the server that Jenkins runs on because it's managed by a separate team, so I can't go into JENKINS_HOME.

I looked into a few ARMs like Nexus and Artifactory, but from my understanding those are only supposed to be used for full releases. I'm looking to save artifacts after every new merge, which can happen multiple times a day.

I'm currently saving them on a functional user's home directory, but I'm the only one with direct access to it so that's no good. I also looked into plugins like ArtifactDeployer, which doesn't support pipelines and only does as much as a 'cp' command as far as I could tell.

Comment: Why would you want to "save artifacts after every new merge, which can happen multiple times", and for how long? All your builds should be reproducible, especially w/declarative pipeline. You only need know what changeset was used for each. Keep only used/useful builds. Either store the changeset id in the MANIFEST or as a property file w/artifacts or tag back the source w/your build label. You can use Nexus for SNAPSHOT objects but you only get back the latest; the rest depend on retention policy. No fan of archiveArtifacts; there's option to store logs outside of jobs, but not artifacts.

Comment: Also, known issue: [JENKINS-37503](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37503)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I plan to use the artifacts for nightly and weekly testing so I don't have to re-build the files as often. They're going to be kept until we start working on a new version of our app, which we do bi-annually. I'd like to keep only certain builds, but every new merge is potentially "useful".

Comment: Every new image is potentially useful until it's not. Once you deploy and it passes test, you probably can discard all the prior ones back to the last key build (ie: the one in Production). You are not likely to have a good build n+2 (where n is in Prod) and then decide, no let's go with n+1, so that becomes discardable. You can mark builds as [Keep this build forever](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218762207-Automatically-Marking-Jenkins-builds-as-keep-forever). Combined with a proper retention strategy, you could mange it with Jenkins (plus groovy automation).

Comment: Makes sense. My Jenkins already saves the artifact from the last successful merge, but my boss asked me to keep all of them just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating some freestyle jobs that copy artifacts from the pipelines and save them directly in their workspace. This way they're stored on our Jenkins slaves and visible through the interface to anyone who has permission to view job workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus does not care what kind of artifacts you drop there. Its a good idea to use it.